# Override Adminhtml Core Controller not working (EE 1.14)

Tags: adminhtml, overrides, controllers

I would like to override the core Controller.

Path: ***app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php***

And then, I create the custom extension for overriding this controller.

Here is my file structure:

config: ***app\code\local\Mypackage\MyModule\etc\config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mypackage_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mypackage_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mypackage_MyModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mypackage_MyModule</Mypackage_MyModule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

controllers: ***app\code\local\Mypackage\MyModule\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php***

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales_OrderController.php';

class Mypackage_MyModule_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    /**
     * View order detale
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Orders'));

        //etc...
    }
}
```

However, it don't work.

Any suggestion for me? Please help. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I am using EE 1.14

**EDIT2:**

I had modified these file:

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mypackage_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mypackage_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mypackage_MyModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml</Mypackage_MyModule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

app\code\local\Mypackage\MyModule\controllers\Adminhtml\Sales\OrderController.php:

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales' . DS . 'OrderController.php');

class Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    /**
     * View order detale
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
        die(":D"); //for test
    }
}
```

But still don't work:(

Modules : ***app/etc/modules/Mypackage_MyModule.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mypackage_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mypackage_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

---

### EDIT3:

I had found the issue. The problem had written on below reply message.

Comment: do you have create Mypackage_MyModule.xml?

Comment: yes. I had done it.

Comment: It still using the core Controller:
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php.

look like not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You included `OrderController.php` wrongly. It should be like this :

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales' . DS . 'OrderController.php');
```

Ensure your development mode is ON and cache is removed. This will definitely point out the error in your codes.

---

Also it is better to move your controllers in a directory called `Adminhtml`. So that you can uniquely distinguish both frontend controller and admin controllers. In order to do this, you need to do this.

#### File : `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mypackage_MyModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml</Mypackage_MyModule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

#### File : `app\code\local\Mypackage\MyModule\controllers\Adminhtml\Sales\OrderController.php`

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales' . DS . 'OrderController.php');

class Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    /**
     * View order detale
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Orders'));

        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I had already turn on the development mode but can't see any error...

Comment: error comes in log files which you can find in `var\log` directory.

Comment: @Mokona you have your module activation file at `app/etc/modules` ?

Comment: yeah. i had done it but still don't work

Answer (score 2):

I have already find out the answer.

As I am using EE 1.14, therefore, my Magento system have another Core programm called "***Enterprise***".

And, I find out Enterprise_SalesArchive this module had already overrided the ***app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php*** once.

***app\code\core\Enterprise\SalesArchive\etc\config.xml***:

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <enterprise_salesarchive before="Mage_Adminhtml">Enterprise_SalesArchive_Adminhtml</enterprise_salesarchive>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Therefore, Here is my answer.

config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mypackage_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mypackage_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mypackage_MyModule before="Enterprise_Salesarchive">Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml</Mypackage_MyModule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

app\code\local\Mypackage\MyModule\controllers\Adminhtml\Sales\OrderController.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'Enterprise/SalesArchive/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php';

class Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Enterprise_SalesArchive_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    /**
     * View order detale
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
        die(":DD"); //for test
    }
}
```

Thanks for you all help.

Answer (score 1):

Admin configuration should be content `Adminhtml` in xml tag so your configuration in `config.xml` will be like below

```
 <!--Admin Configuration -->
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mypackage_MyModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml</Mypackage_MyModule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

And your controller file should be like

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS."Sales".DS."OrderController.php");

class Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController {

 /**
     * View order detail
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Orders'));

        //etc...
    }

}

hope it will work from your end.
```

Comment: It will work without `Adminhtml` . But it is the best practice to keep `Admnhtml` always.

Comment: yes it should be good practice to follow, so someone another programmer can easily work

Comment: thanks for answer. I had modified these files but still don't work:(

Comment: did you clear cache ? or look for any log in log files ? as per above file it should work for sales order detail

Comment: yeah. I had check it but there is no any error log about this controller in system.log(var/log).
and, I had disable the cache function....:(

Answer (score 1):

in config.xml

```
<Mypackage_MyModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml</Mypackage_MyModule>
```

controller path must be.

controllers: `app\code\local\Mypackage\MyModule\controllers\Adminhtml\Sales\OrderController.php`

because it will look for 
so the controller file will be

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales'.DS.'OrderController.php';


class Mypackage_MyModule_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    /**
     * View order detale
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Orders'));

        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I had modified these files but still don't work:(

Comment: i test this code it is working for me. check the error log.

Comment: It still using the core controller..app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php.
I try to die some string at viewAction on this core controller. And.. it just happen...

Comment: maybe issue with camel case change module name to `Mymodule` to every place. and clear the cache or disabled is better for module creation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales_OrderController.php';
```

to

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales'.DS.'OrderController.php';
```

Your code  `Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales_OrderController.php';` generate output like

> Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales_OrderController.php

and which is wrong.

Also you need to change rewrite code at `config.xml`